# Como só pegar só os números do XML

Tags: php, xml

Eu quero pegar só os números do XML com o PHP:

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
...
</OfficeDocumentSettings>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
...
</ExcelWorkbook>
<Styles>
...
</Styles>
<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Planilha1">
<Table ss:StyleID="ta1">
<Column ss:Span="23" ss:Width="48.19"/>
<Column ss:Index="25" ss:Width="74.61"/>
<Column ss:Width="103.95"/>
<Column ss:Span="37" ss:Width="48.19"/>
<Row ss:Height="15">
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">n1</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">n2</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">n3</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">n4</Data>
</Cell>

</Row>
<Row ss:Height="15">
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">4</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>

<Row ss:Height="15">
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="Number">9</Data>
</Cell>
```

**Coisas que já tentei:**

```
    $temporario = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"];

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($temporario);


    foreach($xml->Table->Row->Cell as $Cell) {
        print_r("NUMEROS $Cell\n");
    }
    
    foreach($xml->ss:Worksheet->Row->Cell as $Cell) {
        print_r("NUMEROS $Cell\n");
    }
```

Comment: Deixei uma resposta pra entender melhor como funciona o SimpleXmlElement. Acabei montando um XML próprio, porque na pergunta, o XML tá incompleto

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro detalhe: a função `simplexml_load_file` gera uma instância chamada de `SimpleXmlElement`. E já adianto... essa classe é bem chata de mexer.

Você usa o object separator (o ->) apenas para acessar os nós.

Exemplo:

```xml
<root>
<a>
   <b>
     <c>Eu sou o C</c>
   </b>
</a>
</root>
```

```php
var_dump($xml->a->b->c);
```

Isso vai gerar:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2355 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "Eu sou o C"
}
```

Para acessar os atributos, você deve acessar como se faz com os índices do `array`, usando ['nome_atributo']

Exemplo:

```php
$str = '<root>
<a>
   <b nome="valor" numero="13.55">
     <c>Eu sou o C</c>
   </b>
</a>
</root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

var_dump($xml->a->b['numero']);
```

O resultado será:

```
  [0]=>
  string(5) "13.55"
}
```

Nota: Tudo que é retornado vem como `SimpleXmlElement`. Então, para converter o valor, você precisa fazer um cast, conforme necessário:

```php
var_dump((float) $xml->a->b['numero']); // float(13.55)
```

Para acessar os valores com namespace, segue a mesma regra:

```php
echo (float) $xml->a->b['ss:numero'];
```

### Exibindo nome e atributos usando foreach

Para exemplificar melhor, criei o seguinte XML.

```xml
<root>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell label="ID">1</cell>
            <cell label="NOME">Wallace</cell>
            <cell label="Número">33.55</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell label="ID">2</cell>
            <cell label="NOME">Wayne</cell>
            <cell label="Número">21</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
</root>
```

Como percebi que você está confuso também quanto ao uso do `foreach`, criei um exemplo de como acessar os nós filhos através dele.

Veja:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./dados.xml');


foreach ($xml->table->row as $row) {

    foreach ($row->cell as $cell) {
        echo $cell['label'], ':', $cell, "\n";
    }
}
```

O resultado é

```
ID:1
NOME:Wallace
Número:33.55
ID:2
NOME:Wayne
Número:20.21
```